# Handle Empty lines in Java

Tags: java

I am facing a problem in the following code. I am trying to run the program and it terminates when it hits empty space in my input. How else I should approach this.

```
try {
    BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text.txt);
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> place = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = sc.readLine()) !=null) {
        if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("name")) {
                name.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("id")) {
                id.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("location")) {
               place.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
           }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("details")) {
                details.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
        }
    }
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new File(text.csv));
    pr.println("Name;Id;;Location;Details");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        pr.println(name.get(i) + ";" + id.get(i)  + ";" + place.get(i) + ";"  + details.get(i));
    }
    pr.close();
    sc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  }
```

My Input looks like

name = abc

id = 123

place = xyz

details = hsdyhuslkjaldhaadj

name = ert

id = 7872

place =

details = shahkjdhksdhsala

name = sfd

id = 4343

place = ksjks

Details = kljhaljs

when im trying to execute then above text my program terminates at place = "null"   because of no value there.I need the output as an empty space created in place ="null"   and print the rest as follows in a .csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is a issue,your input file contains key as "place" but your are trying for word "location"

```
 if (line.toLowerCase().contains("location")) { //this must be changed to place
           place.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
       }
```

Modified the code snippet as below.check it

```
   while ((line = sc.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("name")) {
                name.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("id")) {
                id.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("place")) {
                // change done here to add space if no value
                place.add(line.split("=").length > 1 ? line.split("=")[1]
                        .trim() : " ");
            }
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("details")) {
                details.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made those changes but yet showing exceptions like this      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Check.main(Check.java:31)

Comment: what is your line 31?

Answer (score 1):

If you process the location, `line.split("=")[1]` could result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException and `line.split("=")[1].trim()` could result in a NullPointerException.

You can avoid this by testing your parsed result.

Instead of `place.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());`, do `place.add(parseContentDefaultEmpty(line));`, with:

```
private String parseContentDefaultEmpty(final String line) {
    final String[] result = line.split("=");
    if(result.length <= 1) {
        return "";
    }
    final String content = line.split("=")[1];
    return content != null ? content.trim() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting question to line doesn't appear to change what line is read later (if you're wanting the line to advance before it hits the while loop).